# gZipBuffer DECompression Convert from C# to F#

Tags: f#

Hy Guys, so after you help me to properly convert the "Compress" function ,i tryed to convert the Decompress function too

now im here
(decompress function by me)

```
let DecompressString (detext : string) =
    let buffer = Convert.FromBase64String detext
    using (new MemoryStream ()) <| fun memoryStream ->
            using (new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true)) <| fun gzipStream ->
            memoryStream.Position <- 0L
            memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, Array.length buffer)
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
```

the original Compressfunction is

```
let compressString (text : string) =
let buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes text
using (new MemoryStream ()) <| fun memoryStream ->
    using (new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) <| fun gzipStream ->
        gzipStream.Write (buffer, 0, Array.length buffer)
    memoryStream.Position <- 0L
    let compressedData = Array.zeroCreate (int memoryStream.Length)
    memoryStream.Read (compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length)
    let gzipBuffer = Array.zeroCreate (compressedData.Length + 4)
    Buffer.BlockCopy (compressedData, 0, gzipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length)
    Buffer.BlockCopy (BitConverter.GetBytes buffer.Length, 0, gzipBuffer, 0, 4)
    Convert.ToBase64String gzipBuffer
```

if i compress a string like this

```
File.WriteAllText("test",compressString("bla"))
```

(I save the file named "test" in this file is the compressed string from "bla")

"`AwAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1StfgdKEIgGATJNiQQBDswYjN5pLsHWlHIymrKoHKZVZlXWYWQMztnbz33nvvvffee++997o7nU4n99//P1xmZAFs9s5K2smeIYCqyB8/fnwfPyImZfb/ADmz70cDAAAA`" < seems for me bigger then before? :D

ok now i try to decompress it again like:

```
File.WriteAllText("test2",DecompressString(File.ReadAllText("test")))
```

but  in the new "test2" file is only unreadable text like:

"`?"&eï¿½ï¿`"

so i think my dcompress function dont work properly.

Maybe your my heroes can help me out a second and last time ? :)
Anyway thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm if i see it right the compress function only returns a base64 string? ,so i just can use ' Convert.ToBase64String' ,i just wanted a "real" String Compression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the memory stream you're reading from is empty, so nothing will be written to the destination buffer.

Secondly, you're re-using `buffer` and this contains the bytes of the base 64 string argument.

You can't get the Length of a `GZipStream` so you'll have to copy it to another memory stream:

```
let DecompressString (detext : string) =
    let buffer = Convert.FromBase64String detext
    using (new MemoryStream ()) <| fun memoryStream ->
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, Array.length buffer)
        memoryStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
        using (new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true)) <| fun gzipStream ->
            using(new MemoryStream()) <| outStream ->
                gzipStream.CopyTo(outStream)
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outStream.ToArray())
```

Comment: Uff ok thanks for help ,but why is my memorystream empty? ,so your functopn also  dont works il get here"let outBuf: byte array = Array.zeroCreate (int gzipStream.Length)" this exception "This operation is not supported." ,f# is freaking me out but i love it :) thanks for you help anyways its a very good community and sorry for my english :)

Comment: @galeda - Your memory stream is empty because you haven't written anything to it. Your exception is because `GZipStream.Length` is not supported. I'll try to find a solution...

Comment: Ahhhh your right BUT why he write me something like that in the "decompressed" file "?"&eï¿½ï¿" if he empty this should also be empty or? ,but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @galeda - The problem is you're effectively treating a base 64 string as a UTF-8 string, which is why you get garbage returned to you. You read the base 64 bytes into buffer, then you read the empty memory stream into the start of buffer. This does nothing, so you're really doing `Convert.FromBase64String detext |> Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

Comment: Ok i understand , but this makes no sense or? i will compress a string and not convert him to utf/base64 etc this is useless. ,thank you all for your help :)

Comment: @galeda - You can still encode the gzip stream, but you need to write the encoded bytes to the memory stream before you create the `GZipStream`.

Comment: Yes ok, but how this works exactly in f#? ,f# have some freaky syntax i just must learn more about it but im more the "learning by doing guy" :) 
anyway Thank you very much guys for your help :)